# magento 2 add quantity below 1 to cart

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm going insane! I want to add 0,5 to my cart in Magento 2 and it's not working!

I adjusted the "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" to 0.5 and tried everything, but not working.

1.2 is working fine, but 0.9 will not work

link: https://www.huurhulp.nl/tricot-stoffen/stippen/tricot-rood-stippen-8mm.html

I'f i look in the page source i find this section, and i'm thinking that there's the problem.

```
<div class="control">
   <input type="number"
      name="qty"
      id="qty"
      maxlength="12"
      value="0.5"
      title="Qty" class="input-text qty"
      data-validate="{&quot;required-number&quot;:true,&quot;validate-item-quantity&quot;:{&quot;minAllowed&quot;:1}}"
    />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in the line in ProductView.phpThis line seems to disallow min quantities less than 1.

magento/module-catalog-inventory/Block/Plugin/ProductView.php: $params['minAllowed'] = max((float)$stockItem->getQtyMinAllowed(), 1);

I manually set it to 0,5 and that did the job (But not nice...)